# What is the difference between a static and a dynamic control in ASP.NET using webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dynamic-controls

I am having a hard time finding a good answer for this question, but what is the difference between a static and a dynamic control in an ASP.NET webforms application.

Does having a dropdown list declared in html, but databound in code behind deem it a dynamic or static control?

Comment: Dynamic controls must be dealt with differently than static controls, especially in regards to viewstate.

Comment: It is not easy to deal with dynamic controls. Because dynamic controls lose their state at postback. You have to write more codes if u wish to make the controls stay in the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Form has only 3 kind of controls - Server Control, User Control and Custom Server Control.

*You can use all three types of controls in following two scenarios -*

**Static** - You add a control inside ASPX at compile time.

**Dynamic** - You render a control from code behind at run time. *It is not easy especially if you are new to Web Form.*

> Does having a dropdown list declared in html, but databound in code
>   behind deem it a dynamic or static control?

It is a static way of using a control, since you declare the control inside ASPX at compile time.